# Newbie Sharepoint Access Denied on default application

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I'm learning Sharepoint.
I am able to surf to an log in to the admin page.
I try to surf to the default site (port 80) and I am prompted for a login.
I login as the administrator, but I get access denied.
Wouldn't the administrator have access to ALL sites automatically?
This does not seem to be the case, but I cannot find where to grant access to the admin to this site.

Is this not clear or too complicated to easily answer.
Any guidance, where to look?

Comment: What user is the administrator? Is this the machine admistrator, the domain administrator or another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found an area in the admin area to allow public access, and that seemed to work